# How to create an instance of a model upon button press

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a User, Poll, and Vote model.

My user is created at registration and polls are created via a form the user has access to.

Upon showing a particular poll to a user, how can I create a new instance of the vote model when the user clicks a poll option?

Basically I want to create a new vote model instance when the user clicks a button that passes the current user_id and poll_id as parameters as well as a value for the option they selected.

My vote model 3 attributes: poll_id, user_id, and value.

poll_id and user_id are foreign keys to the poll and user tables, and value just records the chosen poll option.

I attempted to try and achieve this by calling Vote.create upon selecting the button like this:

```
<a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light hoverable    red    left" href="<%= poll_path(@next) %>" >
  <i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i>
  <%= Vote.create %>
</a>
```

This is how I'm getting access to the poll_id and user_id inside of my vote create method inside the vote controller

```
@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
@vote.user_id = @current_user
@current_poll ||= Poll.find(session[:poll_id]) if session[:poll_id]
@vote.poll_id = @current_poll
```

Basically, I'm wondering what the correct rails-like way would be to go about this.

Disclaimer: I am very very new to rails and realise that I may be posing this question incorrectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do `Vote.create` in the view. You do that in the controller.

Create a button using the appropriate [helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) in your `.erb` file, the `vote_path`, and passing in `poll_id`, `user_id`, and `value`. That will give you a button in your view that, when clicked, will `POST` to the `create` action on your `VoteController` where you will do the object instantiation and save. From there you do a redirect to where ever is appropriate given the results of the `create` action.

You'll need to go back and [read](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) up on how Rails uses ERB to construct HTML files for rendering in the browser. Your question suggests you haven't really groked it yet.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue:

```
<td><%= button_to '<' ,{:controller => 'votes', :action => 'create', :user_id => 1, :poll_id => @poll.id, :value => 0}, {:method => :post} %></td>
```